# How to kill any running bteq process in Linux?

Tags: linux, sh, teradata

I'm running my BTEQ script with .sh

Sometimes when I kill the .sh process, the BTEQ process hasn't been killed or stopped. BTEQ still runs on background.

So, how to kill both .sh and BTEQ process?

And can I see current BTEQ process that runs on background from one specified TERADATA user?

Answer (score 1):

You can see a list of all running bteq processes on the server with:

```
ps -ef | grep bteq
```

That will show you the user, the process id, and the date it started. That's just two built in Linux commands (ps to see processes which is piped to grep, which searches for the search term "bteq" returning the `ps -ef` line that contains "bteq"`)

Assuming you have appropriate permissions/rights you can use the following command to end all bteq sessions.

```
killall bteq
```

That may have unintended consequences since it would be akin to kicking off a user potentially in the middle of processing a stored procedure or running a large `INSERT INTO` or whatever your folks are running through bteq.

If you want to be more targeted, then find the process id from the `ps -ef | grep bteq` command of the bteq session you want to kill. (the process id will be the first number after the user). Then stick that process id in the command:

```
kill <the process id>
```

Then just that session will be killed without disturbing other running bteq sessions.

Happy hunting!

Comment: Thanks JNevill... I already kill <pid>. I just wonder, does this command (kill) already stop the BTEQ process? Because I inserted a huge file data to one table via BTEQ, and I couldn't drop the table via Teradata SQL Assistant after I kill the BTEQ process. Actually it took a lot of time to drop the table, so I abort the drop process.

Comment: I know there are commands that you can send to Teradata that will continue executing even after ending your session with the database. Like ALTER TABLE, which can recover (I believe) even if the server itself is stopped, after the server comes back up. That being said, I'm not sure about BTEQ's insert process. I can't imagine that it would keep running even after killing the bteq process on the shell, but I guess it's not out of the question. Do you have Viewpoint installed that you could see if the bteq user is still active after the `kill` of bteq?

Comment: I can't check my BTEQ process still running or not. But whenever I try to delete, drop, insert, or update the table, it can't be executed. I guess the session is locked or the BTEQ is stuck in admin level. Is there a way to release the running BTEQ process? But I'm not sure about the privileges.

Comment: Even if it is an old question ...  If you have a insert/update/transaction affecting a lot of data and you kill the bteq session, it may take some time to do the rollback. And it would be better not stop that.